# SVM parameters Optimization

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have optimized the Cost and Gamma parameters of SVM by PSO and and ABC. they found different values for Cost and Gamma. why PSO and ABC found different values for the cost and gamma parameters?

Comment: Maybe the function you're trying to optimize has several local minima, and not just one? maybe a random number generator gets initialized differently between the optimzation runs? Maybe the hyperparameter values found are not *that* different. Difficult to come up with an answer.

Comment: These are meta-heuristics. They not always find the optimal solution.